# How to gauge Excel Calculation speed?

Tags: performance, excel

I am developing an **Excel 2010 Application**, which contains complex calculations in over 60+ worksheets. When I change certain data in any cell, it takes a lot of time in background calculation (I want the calculation to be **automatic**).....

1. Is there any way to find out which formula is taking more time over the other?
2. What is a better approach to improve performance - multiple simple formulas vs. single complex **(MULTISTEP)** formula?

i.e.
`[STEP-1] E1 = C1 * D1`
`[STEP-2] F1 = E1 / B1`
`[STEP-3] G1 = F1 + B1`

**OR**

`[SINGLE STEP] G1 = (C1 * D1 / B1) + A1`

Suggestion will be appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: I believe in the step 3 we should read F1 + A1 (not B1) to compare it to the single step formula

Comment: http://sites.mcpher.com/share/Home/excelquirks/optimizationlink/execution-time-logging

Comment: The performance of more complex formulas would probably be similar to or close to the performance of a bunch of smaller less complex formulas that do the same thing. I don't think you should go down that road - you will just make your spreadsheet less intuitive. - It's best to keep it intuitive - that way you can reason about it better and might be able to find more efficient ways of doing things. As far as actually testing the speed of sections of your spreadsheets, Hans Passant's link seems like what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

As for the second part, if you use ordinary non-volatile functions then multiple simple formulas could be better for two reasons:

1. On simple recalculations (without rebuilding dependency trees) Excel will calculate only the parts that actually changed, e.g. in your single step example if value in `A1` changes then Excel will have to recalculate the expression in the parentheses `(C1 * D1 / B1)` even if values of `C1, D1, B1` are unchanged. When you replace that part with a reference to F1, the value of F1 will not be recalculated if only A1 changes its value.
2. Multiple simple formulas could be better calculated in parallel if you have multiple cores.

another usefull link in addition to MSDN: http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsc.htm

Volatile functions are evil in very large workbooks, especially OFFSET and INDIRECT. They all are recalculated every time anything changes in a file, and they are always calculated in a single thread. Any cell that depends on a cell with a volatile function becomes volatile as well, because all dependencies have to be recalculated every time a volatile function is recalculated. This **viral volatility** in a big file could seriously damage performance. Using many simple formulas helps in this case as well, since many dependencies could remain non-volatile.

From the link above:

> Some Excel features do not use multithreaded calculation, for example:
>
> Data table calculation (but structured references to tables do use
>   MTC). User-defined functions (but XLL functions can be
>   multithread-enabled). XLM functions. INDIRECT, CELL functions that use
>   either the format2 or address options. GETPIVOTDATA and other
>   functions referring to PivotTables or cubes. Range.Calculate and
>   Range.CalculateRowMajorOrder. Cells in circular reference loops.

Once upon a time I inherited a big file that took 30 min to recalculate on a dedicated fast machine and that was due to crazy usage of OFFSETS to access data from a big sheet. Just by moving calculation logic from Excel to Access and importing results via a pivot table I reduced total calculation time to several seconds!

Answer (score 1):

This may help with your first question http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700515%28v=office.14%29.aspx though as can be seen there your question may be close to being off topic as requiring a book to answer it comprehensively. For your second question I'd guess "no discernible difference".